# Confusion about how eigenvectors span the space

Tags: linear-algebra

For the following matrix
$$ T =
\begin{pmatrix}
6 & 3 & 4 \\
0 & 6 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 7
\end{pmatrix}
,$$
the eigenvalues are $\lambda = 6, 6, 7$. When $\lambda = 6$, the textbook [$\textit{Linear Algebra Done Right}$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a60r50XvtVo) says the eigenvectors span the space $((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0))$. But when I plug in $\lambda = 6$ and solve the $(T - \lambda I) = 0$, I get $y = z = 0$ and $x =$ an arbitrary number for the eigenvector. So, shouldn't when $\lambda = 6$, it spans only $(1, 0, 0)$?

Comment: I think you are right. The book has made a mistake.

Comment: This is not a mistake in the book, because the book states that the *generalized* eigenspace (not the eigenspace) corresponding to the eigenvalue 6 equals the span of ( (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I believe you copied down the matrix incorrectly. The video you linked has the 4 and 3 swapped. You are correct that the 6-eigenspace of this matrix is just spanned by $(1, 0, 0)$. However, at 2:38 in the video they write that the *generalized* eigenspace $G(6, T) = span\{(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0)\}$. Recall that an eigenvector is a nontrivial element of the kernel of $T - \lambda I$. A rank $m$ generalized eigenvector is defined to be an element of the kernel of $(T - \lambda I)^m$ that is not in the kernel of $(T - \lambda I)^{m-1}$. Axler is correct in his computation of the generalized eigenspaces.

Indeed, we can see clearly that $(0, 1, 0)$ is not a eigenvector with eigenvalue 6, so it is not in $ker(T-6I)$. However, it is in $ker(T-6I)^2$. Indeed, we can compute $(T-6I)^2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 10\\
0 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$.

Thus $(0, 1, 0) \in ker(T-6I)^2 - ker(T-6I)$, so it is a generalized eigenvector of rank 2 for the eigenvalue 6. The generalized eigenspace for the eigenvalue 6 is spanned by all generalized eigenvectors for 6, so it is indeed $span\{(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0)\}$.

Comment: I have corrected the matrix. It was a typo. Thanks for pointing out the concept of generalized eigenspace. It was not easy for me to realize this fact.

Comment: Glad I could help!